# row-level locks in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, concurrency, mariadb, locking, commit

Here is the issue, when Session 1 is trying to update a table X, the table becomes locked.

What I need is to lock only the row that Session 1 is trying to update, and Session 2 can access or update other rows at the same time.

Session 1: `update X set a=1994 where b =2 //I want to lock only row where b=2, not the whole table X`

Session 2: `update X set a=1951 where b =1 //I need it to work`

PS:

- I don't have access to the code of the application, I need to
  configure it in the database.
- `autocommit=1`
- I am using `innodb_version:  5.5.35-MariaDB-33.0`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that mariadb's innodb implementation works as mysql, you can use section [15.7.3 Locks Set by Different SQL Statements in InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html) in mysql manual to work out what you need to do (emphasis is mine):

> A locking read, an UPDATE, or a DELETE generally set record locks on every index record that is scanned in the processing of the SQL statement. It does not matter whether there are WHERE conditions in the statement that would exclude the row. InnoDB does not remember the exact WHERE condition, but only knows which index ranges were scanned.
>
> ...
>
> If you have no indexes suitable for your statement and MySQL must scan
> the entire table to process the statement, every row of the table
> becomes locked, which in turn blocks all inserts by other users to the
> table. **It is important to create good indexes so that your queries do
> not unnecessarily scan many rows.**

So, create appropriate indexes on your tables in order not to get those locked.

Comment: I am using the database of jbpm, here is the [DDL script](https://github.com/kiegroup/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-db-scripts/src/main/resources/db/ddl-scripts/mysql5/mysql5-jbpm-schema.sql), it contains appropriate indexes, but I am  having this issue.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot debug such a large db structure for you - particularly since I do not know the queries, nor which table you are having problems with! I would say, if you are getting locking issues, then your indexes are probably not as good as you think they are.

Comment: so what I understood is that once the indexes are set properly, the row lock level works by default, there is no other configurations on the database?

Comment: Row level locks work without indexes as well, just are liable to lock the entire table, not just a couple of rows - as you found out!

Comment: To tie this answer to the question, you need `INDEX(b)`.